# Computer wakes up after turning off speakers

Tags: windows, windows-8, audio, sleep, speakers

Windows 8, PC.

I found solutions for when computer wakes up itself because of special network packets. This can be turned off in the device manager -> network devices -> power managment. The same goes for mouse, keyboard..

**However,** when I put my computer to sleep and forget to turn off the speakers first (I usually notice them by the buzzing sound (not a hi-fi)) and I turn them off after computer is asleep, it immediately wakes him up.

Sound devices has no "power managment" tab in device manager, so I wonder how to fix this problem. Is there no solution other than not forgetting to turn the speakers off before the computer? I have a compulsive need to solve this in a more technical way.

additional information: Speakers are plugged via earphone plug / audio jack.

Comment: How are these speakers attached?  USB or earphone plug?

Comment: earphone plugged

Comment: You could try a different sleep level, Currently the default is s3 for most systems. Maybe try s2 or s4.

Comment: If you happen to have a usb sound card you could borrow, I'd be curious if it has the same behavior.

Comment: What sound card do you have? Just want to take a look at specifications.

Comment: Get an earphone splitter/amp.

Comment: My motherboard: ASUS Z87-K. And I have no usb sound card - the problem is not that tiresome for me to ask friends for such a thing.

Comment: I wouldn't like to go for the sleep level alternatives. If I want to hibernate, I hibernate, but usually I want an s3 sleep, so I'll go and try notifications, I guess, but all of these seem like workarounds. I hoped there would be a hidden setting for it or something. I guess I'll just remember to turn them off first. :D Thank you guys for all the tips!

Comment: @Nikolay I have no external sound card. My motherboard is ASUS Z87-K, where my speakers are plugged in.

Comment: Check power settings in the BIOS as well.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. Here's how I (finally) solved it: Try to find out _exactly_ which device is waking up your PC by typing "`powercfg -lastwake`" into a console window right after it comes out of sleep. This will tell you what exact device to look at. Another way to see the wake events is to check the Windows event log (described [here at sevenforums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/179257-wake-source-read-event-viewer-log.html)), but for me that only lists USB-devices as source (and a few wakeups by system timers), which doesn't help much. But maybe you will see the same dev

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect is happening is due to Windows favor of little pop-ups and notifications that seem to take precedence over all else.

When you plug in your headphones or speakers to you headphone jack, I bet that windows give you a little pop up saying something like "a device was plugged into the headphone jack". And probably does the same when you unplug.

So if your computer goes to sleep when it thinks something is plugged in, and then you unplug it (or in this case turn it off), it gives a popup saying that it detected a change in the headphone jack, and hence, wakes the computer up to tell you.

Pointless right? To handle this, you can change the sleep level, as suggested int he comments above, or you could disable the notifications, which IMO would be nicer because they won't bug you anymore.

Comment: If you turn off speakers they remain plugged in to the port of sound card. Sound card can sense if something plugged in or not, but I doubt it will sense power condition of speakers.

Comment: @Nikolay, you'd be surprised at the insignificance that windows will use as an excuse for pop-ups.

Comment: I would like to test out your approach with notifications, although I dislike the idea of disabling them, I would like to accept your answer, if it works. But I don't know how - since I am not sure what specifically you mean by them, I am not sure how to search for it. A hint, maybe? Thx.

Comment: @CaptJak, it's not up to windows to decide. Most likely, [is not even up to the soundcard](http://superuser.com/questions/110933/how-does-a-sound-card-determine-if-headphones-are-plugged-in), it's the jack itself notifying the connection. Your answer would make sense if OP was unplugging the speakers, but turning them off would not trigger notification (think earphones, with no power source)

Comment: few years later and I have the same problem. I have GIgabyte UD3R motherboard with integrated Realtek HD audio. Did not find any settings in a driver utility from tray icon :-\