# No audio playing through headphone jack

Tags: audio

Today, my set of external speakers for my laptop (HP ENVY m6) stopped working suddenly after I unplugged them to move the laptop and then plugged them back in.

The speakers will play audio from other devices (so they're not defective), and now I can't hear audio from anything else plugged into that jack, like headphones.

I have a dual boot of Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 on this laptop, and the jack doesn't work on either OS.

Is the jack faulty? If so, what can I do to get external audio working again?

Comment: Have you ever disassembled the laptop?  Does plugging a device into the headphone jack still mute the laptop speakers?

Comment: I have never opened the laptop or modified any of its hardware. The laptop speakers still mute when a device is plugged into the jack.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it is a problem in both Windows and Ubuntu suggest that it is hardware at fault.

I would guess that there is some kind of switch inside your jack to detect if it is plugged in. Here is a related thread:

[How does a sound card determine if headphones are plugged in?](https://superuser.com/questions/110933/how-does-a-sound-card-determine-if-headphones-are-plugged-in)

The switch may have malfunctioned and over time it heals itself.

Comment: Over time it _always_ heals itself?  Or over time it _might_ heal itself?

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when you have the **external speakers set to default.** We need to set the headphones as default.

Perform the task mentioned below to set headphones as default:

- On the start screen of windows 8 press the ‘Windows key + X’ key on
  the keyboard and then click on control panel and then Hardware and
  sound option.
- Click in Sound, then a new window will open up.
- In the new windows click on the tab "Playback" and right click in the
  window and click on Show Disabled devices.
- Now check if headphones are listed there and right click on it and
  choose enable.
- Highlight that headphones and click on "Set as Default".

---

Or Try this:

- Step 1. Go to the Tiles menu and type "Troubleshooting"
- Step 2. Click on Troubleshooting
- Step 3. Click on Troubleshoot audio playback in Hardware and Sound
  option
- Step 4. Click Next
- Step 5. Choose Headphones and Windows will automatically detect the
  problem
- Step 6. Click on "Apply, fix" button

---

Last we can try is Solution from HP:
http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-PC-Sound-and-Audio/Audio-Not-Working-After-Windows-8-1-Update/td-p/3057191